# Do first order partial derivatives of this function exist at $(0,1)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Do partial derivatives of $f(x,y) = e^{x+y}[x^{\frac{1}{3}}(y-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}+y^{\frac{1}{3}}(x-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}]$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ exist at (0,1)?

Solving directly for $f_x$ and $f_y$ is quite complicated, so I tried the limit definition:

$f_x(x,y)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}$ ;$f_y(x,y)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)}{h}$.

Plugging in $(0,1)$ yields terms like $(-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}$ and $(h-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}$ which could have three solutions (1 real, 2 complex). And I am stuck and don't know how to proceed.

Have I made a mistake somewhere? What would be the right way to tackle the problem?

Comment: No complex numbers here. This is real calculus. What is $f(h,1)-f(0,1)$? It looks like the partial derivative does not exist. Nothing to do with complex numbers. Forget Wolfram.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head in recognising that $a^b$ with $b$ rational but not an integer and $a <0$ is not trivially defined. In this case a reasonable assumption would be that $a^{1/3}$ is the unique and existing real solution of $x^3 = a$, and $a^{2/3} = (a^{1/3})^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

partial derivatives of $f$ do exist at $(0,1)$:
we have $f(h,1)=e^{1+h}(1-h)^{2/3}=e(1+h+o(h))(1-\frac 23 h+o(h))=e(1+\frac 13h+o(h))$ and $f(0,1+h)=e^{1+h}(1+h)^{1/3}=e(1+\frac 43h+o(h))$. However, $f$ is not diffferentiable at $(0,1)$, as
$f(h,1-h)=e(h^{2/3}-1+h)$.

Comment: So the partial derivatives w.r.t. x and y equal $\frac{e}{3}$ and $\frac{4e}{3}$, respectively, right? Since $f(0,1)=e$ and you just subtract $e$ and cancel out the $h$ on the numerator and the denominator.

Comment: Also, do you mean $f(h,1+h)$ for the last bit there?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. $f(h,1-h)=e(-h^{2/3}+1-h)$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not wrong. This function is $f:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb C$ function which is already a complex function, you would probably get some complex answers. Also, a function may have more than one answers as it maybe a multi-valued function.

Comment: Why is this function complex-valued?

Comment: @TedShifrin Because if you plug in any x<1 or y<1, you would get some real values and some complex values cause of the (x-1)^1/3 and (y-1)^1/3 part

Comment: No, $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ is a fine real-valued function on all of $\Bbb R$. It is the inverse of the real-valued function $g(x)=x^3$.

Comment: You're correct, but it does exists few complex solutions to it. for example, you do have few complex roots for $(-1)^{1/3}=\cos(\pi/3)+i\sin(\pi/3)=\cos(\pi)+i\sin(\pi)=\cos(-\pi/3)+i\sin(\pi/3)$

Comment: also refering to wolfram alpha, the function has a complex value. Therefore, the function can be defined as $f:\Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb C^2$ as $\Bbb C$ contains $\Bbb R$